# Detecting push notification event in cordova app after cold start (from notification click)

Tags: ios, cordova, push-notification, pushwoosh

My push notifications contain custom data that helps route the app to the right place when the notification is clicked. These work fine if the app is open or in the background, but don't work when the app is closed. The notification opens the app but my code doesn't detect the referenced notification event so that I can route it.
I have this in AppDelegate.m

```
#ifndef DISABLE_PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS

    - (void)                                 application:(UIApplication*)application
        didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
    {
        // re-post ( broadcast )
        NSString* token = [[[[deviceToken description]
            stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""]
            stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""]
            stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:CDVRemoteNotification object:token];
    }

    - (void)                                 application:(UIApplication*)application
        didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error
    {
        // re-post ( broadcast )
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:CDVRemoteNotificationError object:error];
    }
#endif
```

I have this JS code in place to catch the notification in my app

```
document.addEventListener('push-notification', function(event) {
                             //get the notification payload

                             console.log("incoming PUSH notification!")
                             console.log(event);
                             factory.reactToIncomingPushNotification(event)


                         });
```

My question is how do I reference the notification event in the app once the app has cold started?

I have a cordova/ionic app with pushwoosh as the provider. I am testing on IOS.

Answer (score 0):

If app is terminated, and user want custom data on tap of notification, then didFinishLaunchingWithOptions of AppDelegate is your method as it contains the data in the key called *UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey*

Comment: Thanks. I see that function (and posted it in my question). However, I believe this functionality (ability to send notification data into the app when opened) is baked into the pushwoosh plugin code. I am trying to follow the notification through the pushwoosh delegate.m file but am getting lost. Can't figure out why the JS listener is not getting triggered.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for me was to set a timeout on the pushwoosh broadcast event. It was sending the broadcast before I had set up my listener. This only happened on cold-start apps. For now, I detect if the push notification has the 'onStart' key set to true. If so, I put a 1.3 second timeout on the dispatchEvent function. Here is the modified function for the PushNotification.js file.

```
// file: plugins/pushwoosh-cordova-plugin/www/PushNotification.js 
PushNotification.prototype.notificationCallback = function(notification) {
    var ev = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
    ev.notification = notification;
    // test for the cold start
    var tout = notification.onStart ? 1300 : 10 ;
    setTimeout(function() { 
        ev.initEvent('push-notification', true, true, arguments);
        document.dispatchEvent(ev);
    }, tout);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue, so I tried putting the event listener within the Javascript as early as possible. Then I was able to receive the push notification from Pushwoosh. This means the DOM event has fired before the 'push-notification' listener within you app's JS had been setup.

Using a setTimeout seems to mask the issue via delaying the DOM event and allowing the listener to be ready.

I suggest moving the listener as early as possible.

```
document.addEventListener('push-notification', function(event) {
    ...
})
```

However this might not be idea as the app may not be ready to use the event from the push notification. My solution was to cache the event and check for it after my app had fully booted up.

Hope this helps!